# Ember - Hitting refresh on browser redirects to previous controller?

Tags: ember.js

I have an ember application.
The routes are setup like.

```
customer 
customer/view/:customerId 
customer/dashboard 
customer/device-sharing
```

Customer/dashboard page displays a component, a table, which has a #linkto helper with route customer.device-sharing

This is working as expected.
The issue is, once on device-sharing route, if I am hitting refresh button on browser, the app is being redirected to dashboard route.

EDITED:

router.js:

```
this.route('customers', function() {
  this.route('index', {path: '/'});
  this.route('view', {path: '/view/:device_id'});
  this.route('dashboard', {path: '/dashboard/:customer_id'});
  this.route('device-sharing', {path: '/device-sharing'});
});
```

The thing going wrong is, in the customer.js route file's afterModel function, we are using transitionTo to go to dashboard.

```
afterModel(model) {
  model = model || [];
  if (model.length === 1) {
    console.log('Route parent');
    this.transitionTo('customers.dashboard', this.get('paramValue'));
  }
}
```

Is there any way to check if the device-sharing subroute is active so that we can prevent the transitionTo call.

Regards,

### Ishan

Comment: I think you'll need to share some code for us to help you.

Comment: Am away from my dev-box, will do so as soon as I reach back. Posting router.js will be sufficient?

Comment: It depends where the problem is. That would be a good start (would give some context), but the problem may be in one of your routes or controllers. In addition, I'd suggest routes and controllers for `customer`, `customer/dashboard` and `customer/device-sharing`.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/) of your problem

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to move your `model` and `afterModel` to your `customers/index` route to get the behavior that you're really after. Without seeing more of the code, it's a bit of a guessing game though.

You could use the [currentRouteName method on the RouterService](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/3.1/classes/RouterService/properties/currentRouteName) to check decide whether to transition or not, but I suspect that would be working around an incorrect design and storing up trouble for yourself down the line.